# Displaying bash script output to console or receive the output as mail in /var/spool/mail/{user_name}

Tags: bash, shell, cron

I am new to scripting and cron jobs and still experimenting to get a sense of how I can use them.

I created a simple script that would tell me my IP at the moment

```
#!/bin/bash
#Create the container to hold the output of ip a command
ifco=$(ip a | grep 'scope global' | grep -v virbr0 | grep -oP '(?<=inet\s)\d+\.\d+\.\$

#Printing out the curent IP address
echo "My IP address currently is "$ifco
```

The script does the job and the output is as follows:

```
My IP address currently is 192.168.135.249
```

then I type crontab -e and put the following entry:

```
MAILTO=gui
31 * * * * gui /home/gui/scripts/06/test_ifc.sh > /home/gui/scripts/06/cronoutput.txt 2>&1
```

Then I checked the content of the file cronoutput.txt and it tells me:

```
/bin/sh: gui: command not found
```

Also when I type the **mail** command I'd expect to have an email with the command output since I've got a **MAILTO=gui{my user}** but there were no emails.

Please tell me how I can receive an email or display the output of my script on the console

p.s. i typed **tty** which gave me **/dev/pts/0**, so I changed my cron entry to be:

```
31 * * * * gui /home/gui/scripts/06/test_ifc.sh > /dev/pts/0
```

However, this did not work as well.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: For collecting the IP address, try this instead: `ip -4 -j a s virbr0 scope global | jq -r .[0].addr_info[0].local` it is more efficient and reliable than grep parsing the localized human-readable layout output of `ip`.

Comment: Understood. However, do you believe that this might be the reason for the error in the cron job? Thanks for your advice.

Answer (score 0):

I nailed it.
CRON wants the full path to the **ip** command. So my script should be like:

```
#!/bin/bash
#Create the container to hold the output of ip a command
ifco=$(/usr/sbin/ip a | grep 'scope global' | grep -v virbr0 | grep -oP '(?<=inet\s)\d+\.\d+\.\$

#Printing out the curent IP address
echo "My IP address currently is "$ifco
```